# I get an error when I open a SharePoint 2013 folder from CMIS Workbench

Tags: 2013, error, cmis, workbench

I want to manage a SharePoint 2013 repository using CMIS Workbench.
After creating a folder, I double click it in order to open it.

[image]

Then I get this error:

"CMIS Exception: connection Unexpected document! Received: HTML document"

[image]

This is the log I can get from CMIS Workbench:

```
> 09:46:03 DEBUG ent.bindings.spi.http.DefaultHttpInvoker: Session c3acc110-ccfe-4444-9dcf-f295fc479bff: GET http://sharepoint2013/my/personal/usuario1/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/d4ebfef0-c49b-4f18-a9fd-d870a70ee206?getChildren&folderID=673&filter=*&includeAllowableActions=false&includeRelationships=none&renditionFilter=cmis%3Anone&includePathSegment=false&maxItems=10000&skipCount=0
> 09:46:04 TRACE ent.bindings.spi.http.DefaultHttpInvoker: Session c3acc110-ccfe-4444-9dcf-f295fc479bff: GET http://sharepoint2013/my/personal/usuario1/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/d4ebfef0-c49b-4f18-a9fd-d870a70ee206?getChildren&folderID=673&filter=*&includeAllowableActions=false&includeRelationships=none&renditionFilter=cmis%3Anone&includePathSegment=false&maxItems=10000&skipCount=0 > Headers: {null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], SharePointError=[0], SPIisLatency=[0], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.5], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], request-id=[2945529f-d6a8-7067-192f-fa0e1d54581a], Date=[Thu, 14 May 2020 07:46:03 GMT], X-MS-InvokeApp=[1; RequireReadOnly], SPRequestGuid=[2945529f-d6a8-7067-192f-fa0e1d54581a], Cache-Control=[private], SPRequestDuration=[101], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], Set-Cookie=[WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated={961e56fc-79db-4287-870c-1ccddfa2ea22}; path=/], Content-Length=[9247], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET], X-SharePointHealthScore=[2], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=utf-8]}
> 09:46:04 ERROR hemistry.opencmis.workbench.ClientHelper: CmisConnectionException: Unexpected document! Received: HTML document
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException: Unexpected document! Received: HTML document
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.parse(AbstractAtomPubService.java:685)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.NavigationServiceImpl.getChildren(NavigationServiceImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl$2.fetchPage(FolderImpl.java:279)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.AbstractIterator.getCurrentPage(AbstractIterator.java:131)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.CollectionIterator.hasNext(CollectionIterator.java:41)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.model.ClientModel.loadFolder(ClientModel.java:233)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.worker.LoadFolderWorker.doInBackground(LoadFolderWorker.java:134)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)> 09:46:04 ERROR hemistry.opencmis.workbench.ClientHelper: Error code: 0
```